# Express auth on a create-react-app project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, create-react-app

I'm working on a simple project with an Express backend and a Frontend bootstrapped with `create-react-app`:

```
my-project
|- server.js         # backend entry point
|- client/
|--  package.json    # client package.json
|--  index.js        # client entry point
```

Following some guides ([like this](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/)), I have now a working backend service on `localhost:3001` and a working frontend service on `localhost:3000`.

All the api calls made to `/api/myapi` are successfully redirect to the port 3001 with a proxy server. In my client package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
```

Now, all is working fine but I have hard times making the login working.
Indeed, I'm not able to redirect the user to a login page when he visit the `/login` url. Inside my `server.js` file:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.send('This is the login page');
});
```

This is simply not working and the url `/login` gives me a blank page instead (it looks like it's not on the port 3001 at all).

Since this is one of my first experience with Express, can someone be so kind to explain me why this is not working?

Comment: Can you show more code? Specifically the ajax request you make to your /login route and what you are doing with the data sent back with res.send.

Comment: Well, this is actually all my code! :D I'm going to replace the res.send static text with a login.ejs page. But, for now, I don't have anything else to show since I stucked on hitting the `/login`

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs in create-react-app, the proxy (as a string in package.json) will only work on non text/html requests.

```
Any unrecognized request without a text/html accept header will be redirected to the specified proxy.
```

Try doing it manually: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuring-the-proxy-manually